# sIFR swf implementation problems

Tags: jquery, flash, sifr

I have tried a few methods of sIFR implementations, but I cant get it to work 100%. I would really appreciate any help or tips on this issue.

I have mainly tried to use sIFR 3 (r436) and I get it to work with the rockwell.swf that is supplied in the example, but I can't get it to work with any other .swf-file

The font I want to use is one called Swedbank (PostScript Mac), but another one called Telenor (Truetype) would be OK aswell. I want to use the font on the H3 tag.

I use the supplied sifr.fla to generate the .swf file in Adobe Flash CS4. All the export settings are according to http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use (flash 8, as2, compress & protect and so on). But when I use my swedbank.swf instead of the rockwell.swf it does not work

I have also tried the sIFR Generator wizard at http://www.sifrgenerator.com/ 
It only supports Truetype. I have tried the Telenor font since it Truetype, and 2-3 other Truetype fonts, but not a single on generates a working .swf-file

I was suspecting that it was some restrictions on these typefaces, so I have tried exporting Arial, Verdana and so on, but it doesn't work either!. I have tried using Rockwell (Opentype) from Flash CS4 but even this one does not work! Since Rockwell is used in the working example, I think that there is not an issue with my choices of typefaces, it must be something else?

I am using OS X 10.5.6, but have tried the above methods on Windows XP aswell.

Can anyone out there suggest a solution or get a working .swf from these fonts?

I have also tried the jQuery sIFR plugin, based on sIFR 2.0.5. This version has issues with Flash 10 I think, but with this plugin I can get a swedbank.swf to work!!..   I generated a swedbank_j.swf file from Flash CS4  and it works fine! But the implementation is very buggy and I do not wish to use jQuery sIFR. I have been experimenting with OffsetLeft and Zoomlevel etc., but the left position is inconsistent and unpredictable and I can not get the result I want with this method

Examples:
http://www.easytowah.com/test/rockwell_sifr3.html
(working with the rockwell example swf file)
http://www.easytowah.com/test/swedbank_sifr3.html
(not working... )
http://www.easytowah.com/test/swedbank_jquery.html
(swf working, but not the implementation)

All the file used in above examples
http://www.easytowah.com/test/sifrtest.zip

The fonts:
http://www.easytowah.com/test/swedbank_osx.zip
http://www.easytowah.com/test/telenor_tt.zip

Documentation/download jquery sIFR: 
http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/

Documentation/download sIFR3: 
http://novemberborn.net/sifr3

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try removing "font-weight: bold;" from your code.
If you view the actual swf file:

http://www.easytowah.com/test/swedbank.swf

Now compare it to the rockwell one:

http://www.easytowah.com/test/rockwell.swf

Rockwell has 3 different styles/weights exported, yours only has one.

Since you don't have a bold in your swf i'd say thats why its not showing

Comment: It took me some headaches to try and get this to work! Never even thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything in Flash CS4 if you can't even get Arial to work!

Have you used other tools such as:

- [sifrgenerator](http://www.sifrgenerator.com/wizard.html)
- [tutorial](http://designintellection.com/2008/this-is-how-you-get-sifr-to-work/)
- [Command line](http://www.mtasc.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need to convert opentype fonts for use with tools like sIFR Generator, you can use this converter: https://onlinefontconverter.com